# RadCartesianChart Setting

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, telerik

I use Telerik component for serial port plot data on chart, I need to know how can i have more space between X-Axis item now x-axis show compressed and i need to know if the plot point increase how can add chart auto scroll,this is my XAML code :

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="myChart" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                <telerik:CartesianChartGrid/>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                <telerik:CategoricalAxis IsStepRecalculationOnZoomEnabled="True" LabelOffset="0" LastLabelVisibility="Visible" LineThickness="1" MajorTickOffset="0" MajorTickLength="5" MajorTickInterval="1" PlotMode="BetweenTicks" SmartLabelsMode="None" TickThickness="1" ZIndex="0"/>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <telerik:LinearAxis BorderThickness="0,4,0,0">
                    <telerik:LinearAxis.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF0E0EF5" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </telerik:LinearAxis.BorderBrush>
                    <telerik:LinearAxis.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFE41F1F" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </telerik:LinearAxis.Background>
                </telerik:LinearAxis>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

I was push my project to [Github](https://github.com/ZimaSystem/TryChartView)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, Add those tag to `radCartesianChart` root element

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
HorizontalZoomRangeStart="0.9"
HorizontalZoomRangeEnd="1"
```

Complete format :

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart
  x:Name="myChart"
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  HorizontalZoomRangeStart="0.9"
  HorizontalZoomRangeEnd="1"
  Margin="0,0,445,162">
```